# Odoo 13 configure workers and limit_memory_hard, limit_memory_soft, max_cron_threads

Tags: google-cloud-platform, odoo, odoo-13

i have installed odoo 13 on google cloud  ubuntu 18 server
specification is 10 GB of RAM

2 vCPUs and 4 GB memory

how to calculate:

- Number of workers
- limit_memory_hard
- limit_memory_soft
- max_cron_threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/administration/deployment/deploy.html#builtin-server%20%20%20Comment%20%20Share%20More%20%20Answer) the rule of thumbs are.

```
Worker number calculation

Rule of thumb : (#CPU * 2) + 1

Cron workers need CPU

1 worker ~= 6 concurrent users

memory size calculation
We consider 20% of the requests are heavy requests, while 80% are simpler ones

A heavy worker, when all computed field are well designed, SQL requests are well designed, … is estimated to consume around 1GB of RAM

A lighter worker, in the same scenario, is estimated to consume around 150MB of RAM

Needed RAM = #worker * ( (light_worker_ratio * light_worker_ram_estimation) + (heavy_worker_ratio * heavy_worker_ram_estimation) )
```

But these are general cases you might need less or more.

In your case, I would go with this and then improve from there based on your cron jobs/request.

```
Number of workers = 5
limit_memory_hard = defualt
limit_memory_soft = defualt
max_cron_threads = 2
```

Comment: Hi, I have the same question, how to calculate limit_memory_soft and limit_memory_hard? I have posted this new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68756173/odoo14-questions-about-limit-memory-soft-and-hard