# Odoo14 - Questions about limit_memory soft and hard

Tags: performance, memory, configuration, odoo, worker

I'm trying to figure out how memory limits work and how to choose the right values.

My test server (VM) has 16GB of RAM and 4 vCPUs but it is a shared server, so I choose to use only 2 vCPUs and 2GB of RAM.

I look in the official documentation, and I calculate how many workers  and RAM  I need (https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/administration/install/deploy.html#worker-number-calculation) .

- W = Workers (workers)
- 2 workers for 1 CPU
- CW = Cron Workers (max_cron_threads)
- TW = W + CW

**Worker number calculation**

(#CPU * 2) + CW

(2 * 2) + 1 = 5 theorical maximal workers

**Memory size calculation**

```
Needed RAM = W * ( (light_worker_ratio * light_worker_ram_estimation) + (heavy_worker_ratio * heavy_worker_ram_estimation) )

5  *  ((0.8 * 150) + (0.2 * 1024)) = 1624 (~2GB of RAM).
```

Ok, now, I go to the "configuration sample" (https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/administration/install/deploy.html#id5) and I see I need to estimate how many  concurrent users I'll have.

Can you confirm that the number of concurrent users includes all website visitors and not only the connected users?

In the configuration sample, how do you calculate/estimate the value of the limit? (limit_memory_hard, limit_memory_soft, limit_request, limit_time_cpu, limit_time_real)

I've read a lot of documentations (official or not), but they never say how to calculate these values.

Examples:

- https://github.com/DocCyblade/tkl-odoo/issues/49 (I really don't understand how DocCyblade finds its values with its formula)
- https://github.com/DocCyblade/tkl-odoo/blob/master/overlay/etc/odoo/openerp-server.conf
- https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-odoo-14-on-ubuntu-20-04/
- https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-speed-up-odoo/. 2048 is the default value since Odoo 10, not 640. If I try its formula, I will find that :

```
limit memory soft : 5 * 2147483648 = 10737418240
limit memory hard : 5 * 2684354560 = 13421772800
```

Can you help me, please?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find the answer for this?

Comment: @glupeksha Unfortunately no...

Comment: Thanks for the above links. Anyway you can get an idea on how to estimate the number of concurrent users by referring to this forum post. https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/how-many-workers-do-i-need-with-odoo-sh-145771